# Favorite Questions and Answers from fourth quarter of 2013

Tags: discussion, blog

Please link to your favorite questions and answers which were either asked or answered from October 1st 2013 through December 31st 2013.

I'm going to compile list to post to the blog. This will be the same format as previous posts.

I will be using DavRob60's queries for a baseline, but I really appreciate people voicing the ones they really enjoyed. Maybe you feel like you answered one really well, even if it didn't receive a lot of votes. Let me know about it.

- [Questions with most **Votes** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106579/questions-with-most-votes-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2013/07/01)
- [Questions with most **View** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106705/questions-with-most-view-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2013/07/01)
- [Questions with **best answer** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106709/questions-with-best-answer-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2013/07/01)

Comment: \*crickets\*...

Comment: @Dvk when it comes to the blog, that is usually the sound I get from the community.

Comment: I was planning to blog about the contest... but the blog post apparently will be the same crickets

Comment: I welcome a post about the contest, even if I'm the only one who reads it.

Answer (score 1):

**Questions** (it was a good quarter for  Star Wars :)

- [Was the Cantina music deliberately off-tune or just an artifact of cheap production?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/41339/was-the-cantina-music-deliberately-off-tune-or-just-an-artifact-of-cheap-product) (user17807).

  I'm deeply partial to music questions, especially Star Wars music questions. And I love love love Cantina music. Used it as lullaby. This one was great - coming out of non-SciFi expertise, but connected to the Universe.
- [How did Jabba become such a powerful crime lord?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/46391/how-did-jabba-become-such-a-powerful-crime-lord) (Beofett).

  Good opportunity to delve into C-canon and an interesting real world parallel.
- [Why do the lightsaber moves of Luke Skywalker look so uncoordinated and crude compared to the prequels?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/45283/why-do-the-lightsaber-moves-of-luke-skywalker-look-so-uncoordinated-and-crude-co) (Vadr).

  Good observation and led to a great answer.

**Answers**:

- [Was the Cantina music deliberately off-tune or just an artifact of cheap production?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/41339/was-the-cantina-music-deliberately-off-tune-or-just-an-artifact-of-cheap-product/41341#41341) (DVK).

  It was a pleasure to dig into this and a very interesting fact to share to the world. I love music questions.
- [Why do the lightsaber moves of Luke Skywalker look so uncoordinated and crude compared to the prequels?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/45283/why-do-the-lightsaber-moves-of-luke-skywalker-look-so-uncoordinated-and-crude-co/45312#45312) (Dacio)

  Great answer, combining in-universe knowledge and out-of-universe as well. Plus, it mentioned Bob Anderson.
- [Who or what was Tom Bombadil?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1586/who-or-what-was-tom-bombadil/46928#46928) (Jimmy Shelter) - **most under-appreciated answer award #1**
- [Why are there humans in the Star Wars Universe?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4073/why-are-there-humans-in-the-star-wars-universe/45842#45842) (Izkata) - **most under-appreciated answer award #2**
- [Reference for the first name of Sirius Black's mother, known from her portrait: Walburga](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/46203/reference-for-the-first-name-of-sirius-blacks-mother-known-from-her-portrait/46204#46204) (Slytherincess)

  Typical deep knowledge of all universe related sources.